# Ruby substract a link from a link

Tags: ruby

i have link like this below. this is generated by some machine.

```
link = 'https://bt.sandal.com/promo/v1/clicks/8a-xgVY2gmUE6AUd6AyR6AJDUMVj9RzNrc1i6sJDUSC5rfB7q3YXUstObm-7q3OBUsthosJpHAJO6_yabm-pHOYDQfri6i-B812kgJxGgBBXZSgjH7NDZ325q1OAZ9o-Q1dFyfFN8B29zSBgHMP2_fB-oJhk3_u6uVjh_32VH7OEqRxo8jJF_9B-P7B2PfBiQ_BO3_-o8V2W33BHe72fyfODQMV9o3gqzOgR3A-Q_BNyuPjrc-D692xzpBR3A-Dq7BkQfBoe7BpZ3NcHu2yZsuyHO-JzSoiHfedgjx6Hc-y8AxizJNM_32-HjN_Z9o-QjNkysoGQVKaZSBiHfzE3Bo-QjNkysoGQVKp_Mhg3J2ky1o-ojBk_9x6q_zN_uzS81OEu9Boqjjp_BzC8jBXHA7ibm-SzBu5_uVGgcPirJ1a11UfrcxGH3UNQfBo6_x-oJPmQiUDUMVDgaUEUSo7QuYDHOYDHBYDHZUDUMNOQ3-BrBY5gBYxgIHi6sUFbm-XP3Oig9-wy3zp9R-BrZUEHsnDUMoxPVY2gIHi6BDfHZF7H_yDHsUfou7DUMNwyfVXgcBjy9zB9fVjraUEH_nabm-N9RoOgfPBrRzwy9z7rMBiP9zBUs2QUsUaos1ibmUOH_UibmU7Hs1ibmUaopyNUiFiHsUfHZ-Pwe?r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sandal.com%2Fbaru-1%2Fsandal-new-shawllow%3Fsrc%3Dtopsearchs&src=search&is_search=true'
```

it looks messy it is. i do not know what type link is that called. but inside the link there is actually link like this

```
https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sandal.com%2Fbaru-1%2Fsandal-new-shawllow
```

how do i extract the link i wanted from the first link in ruby?.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the combination of `URI.parse` and `URI.decode_www_form` to extract the link from the query parameters.

```rb
require 'uri'

parsed_link = URI.parse(link)
query_params = URI.decode_www_form(parsed_link.query).to_h
query_params['r'] # => "https://www.sandal.com/baru-1/sandal-new-shawllow?src=topsearchs"
```